# SignalR Core hub communicating with SignalR .NET client?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a Windows Service (based on the older .NET 4.5 framework) installed on several workstations. There's a limitation that the .NET framework cannot be upgraded. I am implementing a SignalR hub that needs to communicate with this service. I was planning on using SignalR Core for this. But can a SignalR Core Hub talk to a client that's on the .NET 4.5 framework? What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot mix SignalR CORE with SignalR for .NET 4.5. They will not communicate with each other. If you cannot upgrade from .NET 4.5 then stick with the .NET SignalR Server and Client. As long as it meets your needs and until you can upgrade then it's a completely viable solution.

Comment: Thanks. Is .NET SignalR hub supported by Azure SignalR?

Comment: I have not used but it's in the docs... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites